# Markets are visible and highlight but not accessible

Tags: the-banner-saga

I'm currently in Boersgard and I'm unable to access the market place, the market highlights when I hover the mouse pointer over it but clicking on it just makes a clicking sound.

This has also been the case in the last 2 towns I've visited but I thought maybe this was because the towns were sparsely populated with no-one to man the market but it really seems like this 1 should be accessible.

Can anyone confirm if this is a bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've found the answer on the developers website, the bug was introduced in a release and is being fixed in a hotfix to be released very shortly: http://stoicstudio.com/forum/showthread.php?3314-The-Banner-Saga-Patch-2-Release-Notes-2-6-45&p=29972#post29972